# Linked List From User Input c++

Tags: c++

I need to get user input strings and put them into a linked list coding in c++.  I have made it so that I get user input and put it into part of the list, my problem is it only saves one into the list.  I think the problem is I only have one object in the linked list and keep overwriting it, that being said I've tried to fix it but can't find out how.  I also have to organize the list into alphabetical order but 1 step at a time.  Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    string data;
    Node *next;
};

void addToList(Node *head);
void deleteFromList(Node *head);
void printList(Node *head);

int main(){
    bool quit = false;
    int choice;
    Node *head = new Node;
    head->next = NULL;

    while (!quit){
        cout << "1. add to list" << endl
            << "2. delete from list" << endl
            << "3. print list" << endl
            << "4. quit" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        switch(choice){
        case 1: addToList(head);
            break;
        case 2: deleteFromList(head);
            break;
        case 3: printList(head);
            break;
        case 4: quit = true;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "That is not a valid input, quitting program";
            quit = true;
        }
    }
}

void addToList(Node *head){
    bool quit = false;
    string temp;
    Node *current = new Node;
    current->next = NULL;

    while (!quit){

        cout << "Enter a word(quit to stop)";
        cin >> temp;

        if (temp == "quit"){
            quit = true;
        }
        else{
            current->data = temp;
            current -> next = current;
        }
    }
    return;
}

void deleteFromList(Node *head){
    string deletion;
    cout << "Which value do you want to delete from the list? ";
    cin >> deletion;

    Node *prev = head;
    Node *current = head->next;

    while (current)
    {
        if (current->data == deletion){
            prev->next = current->next;
            delete current;
            return;
        }
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    if (!current){
        cout << "That value is not in the list" << endl;
    }
}

void printList(Node *head){
    if (!head)
    {
        cout << "Nothing is in the list." << endl;
        return;
    }

    Node *current = new Node;
    current->next = head;
    while (current)  
    {
        cout << current->data << endl; 
        current = current->next;  
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

In function addToList, you allocate just one node even if the user add more than one word. You need to allocate the new nodes in the loop, when the user doesn't enter "quit". The following code should be correct:

```
void addToList(Node *head){
    bool quit = false;
    string temp;
    Node *current;

    while (!quit){

        cout << "Enter a word(quit to stop)";
        cin >> temp;

        if (temp == "quit"){
            quit = true;
        }
        else{
            // Allocate the new node here:
            current = new Node;
            current->data = temp;

            // the new node is inserted after the empty head
            // because head is an empty node in your implementation:
            current->next = head->next;
            head -> next = current;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

And in the fuction printList, you don't need to instantiate a new node:

```
void printList(Node *head){
    // head->next, because the head is an empty node in your implementation,
    // but be carefull, head had to never be NULL in your program,
    // so you should also check if head is NULL.
    if (!head->next)
    {
        cout << "Nothing is in the list." << endl;
        return;
    }

    Node *current;
    // set current to head->next, because the head is empty in your implementation:
    current = head->next;
    while (current)
    {
        cout << current->data << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this-

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct node 
{
  int data;
  node* next;
};
void printlinkedlist(node* node)
{
  int c=0; //taken just for good looking output
  while(node!=NULL)
  {
    if(c>0)
    {
      cout<<"->"<<node->data;
      node = node->next;
    }
    else
    {
      cout<<node->data;
      node = node->next;
      c++;
    }
  }
}
int main() {
  int n;
  cout<<"Enter no. of nodes=";
  cin>>n;
  int num,c=0; //initialized c for setting head with second node..
  node* head = new node; //initialized head node
  node * temp = new node; //initialized temp node 
  cin>>num;
  head->data=num;
  for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
  {
    if(c==0)
    {
      cin>>num;
      temp->data=num;
      head->next=temp; //head point to second node i.e. temp
      c++;
    }
    else
    {
      cin>>num;
      node * temp1 = new node; //initialize other temp node for every value 
      temp1->data=num;
      temp->next=temp1; //point to temp1 to temp 
      temp=temp1; //set temp as temp1 
    }
  }
  printlinkedlist(head); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should edit addToList 
Replace:

```
current->next=current;
```

With:

```
head->next=current;
```

Brcouse you was repointing current with that pointer.
By the way, your question was: Why this code doesn't add data properly? Hope it helps